# Spark 1.3 missing libraries

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using spark 1.3 with **cdh-5.4.7**. it's not allowed for me to use maven or sbt; so i'm using spark-shell, i add jars using **`--jars`** command.

My problem is: i have a task to send from spark to kafka and from spark to **hbase (0.98.6)**; i saw many tries here but all of them dosnt slove my problem.

I download many kafka and hbase jars but they didnt work.
does anyone have this kind of problem? and how i can slove it ?
thank you